# How can I match a dynamic route in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table like this:

```
// routes
+----+-----------------------------+
| id |           route             |
+----+-----------------------------+
| 1  | /tracking_code/expire/{id}  |
| 2  | /tracking_code/list         |
+----+-----------------------------+
```

`{}` means a dynamic value. And I need to match the first row for this entry value: `/tracking_code/expire/2`. I guess I need to use regexp. Any idea how can I do that?

---

My current workaround is using `LIKE` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM routes WHERE route LIKE :entry%
```

Also I should remove that number of the end of entry like *`/tracking_code/expire/`*.

Sadly my approach won't work for complicated routes like this: `/tracking_code/expire/{id}/temp`. Anyway, how should I use regexp for this?

Comment: Is all the route have the same format, i mean start with `/tracking_code/expire/` followed by a number or what there are other format?

Comment: You can't pass `/tracking_code/expire/2` barely into a magical function which takes a route without any delimiters like `/tracking_code/expire/{2}`. If you do this anyway you'll encounter conflicts and costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**RLIKE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) like this

```
SELECT * FROM routes WHERE route RLIKE '^.*[0-9]+.*$'
```

to replace using regex i don't think this is possible, but there are some sneaky way, read this post here [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

- [MySql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/301c7f/1)
- [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tFo9Vn/1)